# boost::shared_ptr used with vector is slow?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost

I have used a vector of boost shared pointers

```
class Example{

vector<boost::shared_ptr<Point3f> > vec1;
vector<boost::shared_ptr<Point3f> > vec2;
vector<boost::shared_ptr<Point3f> > vec3;

};
```

point3f is struct with 3 floats, I push_back 50000 elements in vec1,vec2,vec3.
It works totally fine. but use of this kind of vector has increased the destruction time of this class. 
A possible explanation which I can think of is whenever vector object is destroyed, then for each object inside vector, destructor is called.
So is it making the destruction slow ?

Should I use C style malloc and free or C++ style new and delete to manage memory?

Comment: Do you need them to be `shared_ptr`s at all to begin with?

Comment: Yup because I do not know in the beginning How many elements are there...,I can also use objects of Point3f but everytime I push an object copy constructor is called which further increases the cost of pushing data, and I dont have to care about memory leaks using shared_ptr

Comment: @Ujjwal: that is not the reason why you need `shared_ptr`, that's the reason why you need `vector`

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. You have a `std::vector`. You can push as many elements in there as you like. Just make it a `std::vector<Point3f>`. No memory leaks to worry about at all.

Comment: @Bart: only if the Point3f object is copyable & this doesn't take much time. But from the name one could assume that it's just 3 floats. And with 3 floats, you are totally right.

Comment: @TobiasLangner The OP says "point3f is struct with 3 floats", so I'm assuming all this pointer business is pure overkill.

Comment: @Bart: although I tend very much to agree with you, I guess in the end it depends on the particular application logic. If those points must be part of several collections and the change of one point must affect the corresponding entry of other collections, then you just need reference semantics. And if you want to do it safe, you need a `shared_ptr`. Anyway I'm not saying that this is necessarily the case of this question, just contributing to the discussion.

Comment: @AndyProwl I couldn't agree more. In this particular case though I have the sneaking suspicion the OP simply wants to store some points without the particular application logic you mention. Which sparked my initial comment. Something for the OP to consider. I of course don't know the particular use-case.

Comment: @Bart: your suspicion is right - see the comment he wrote to the answer below. So I withdraw my objection ;-)

Comment: Are you measuring the speed of the optimized program or the debug program?  Some STL implementations have *lots* of error checking in debug mode, and the difference between opt and debug can be tremendous.  Make sure you have a problem before you try to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

A `shared_ptr` has the additional overhead of doing reference counting. For example

```
vec1.push_back(sp);
vec2.push_back(sp);
vec3.push_back(sp);
```

For each copy, the reference counter is incremented. For each destruction, the reference counter is decremented. Only when it reaches `0`, the object itself is destroyed.

Destruction will take some time if the object is non-trivial anyway, the overhead introduced by the `shared_ptr` will only be noticeable if the destructor is much bigger than the increment/decrement operation.

To see if the source is actuall your use of the `shared_ptr`, you can compare the times you have now with just using raw pointers and deleting them manually.

Make sure the vectors don't re-allocate though. Specify the size in advance, or use `reserve` or `resize` - this can be a bottleneck for large vectors combined with smart pointers.

Comment: It is for sure that the object I push inside a vector is not referenced by any other shared_ptr outside vector, but I take that point of overhead .. of reference count... so that means before doing destruction it does an extra check to see whether its zero or not.,I will try with raw pointers....

Comment: @Ujjwal: don't try raw pointers. If the objects in that vector are not referenced by other `shared_ptr`s, then it means you do not need pointers at all. All you need is plain value semantics. Just have a `vector<Point3f>` collection

Comment: @Ujjwal I agree with Andy, if you don't need pointers (polymorphic behavior), just use objects.

Comment: @AndyProwl I take your point....I will use vector<Point3f>...it seems OK...to use that in this scenario... :). Just out of curosity to find is it really the problem with shared_ptr's I will try with raw ptrs..

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: it is not much about polymorphic behavior, rather reference semantics. you may need to create aliases without having derived classes and inheritance involved, and that would likely justify the use of `shared_ptr`. but the OP has just excluded this case

Comment: @AndyProwl agree, but if he did need polymorphic behavior, he would need pointers. (which is what I mistakenly assumed)

Comment: @Ujjwal: you can try it out of curiosity, just be aware that raw pointers lead to a huge number of problems. first of all, you must make sure they are not *dangling* (i.e. they do not refer to objects which have gone out of scope). to avoid that, you would normally allocate objects on the heap with `new`, but that means you might forget deleting them with `delete`, which would lead to *memory leaks*. avoiding to use `shared_ptr`s often gives you a *false* sense of performance gain, because you might have to do the same things that `shared_ptr`s do *manually* - and you could make mistakes.

Comment: @Ujjwal: so in the end it's not much the `shared_ptr` to be blamed about bad performance, but rather the requirements of your application logic (being able to *safely share* some objects). `shared_ptr` is likely the most efficient way to do that. in order to achieve a *real* performance gain, you most likely have to change the application logic - for instance, not using reference semantics in this case.

Comment: @AndyProwl I take your suggestions and I will take care when using raw pointers... I will not be using raw Pointers in my current code...I will make separate code to try it out....But I have learned something new about when to use shared pointers, delighted :)

Comment: @Ujjwal: great, so have fun with your experiments ;)

Comment: FWIW, if you really do need pointers in a vector, it's probably preferable to use Boost's pointer vector, rather than `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `boost::ptr_vector` if you don't need reference counted objects.

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>

boost::ptr_vector<Point3f> vector;
vector.push_back(new Point3f()); // safe!
```

Alternatively, with C++11, you can use `std::unique_ptr` to achieve the same thing, since unlike `boost::scoped_ptr`, it has copy semantics.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Point3f>> vector;
vector.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Point3f>(new Point3f())); // also safe!
```

Both approaches have performance almost identical to that of a vector of raw pointers, and are of course far easier to use, and safer to work with.

Comment: If we observe closely, if we use a ptr_Vector as u suggest, or a vector shared ptr which I used,The objects to which these pointers point were not contagiously allocated, so  in this case also destruction would be slow, if I use vector<Point3f> the data would be contagiously allocated and thus can be freed faster...

Comment: If a vector<Point3f> meets your needs, then great!  Otherwise, you could also use a custom allocator.